# What is use of <> angle bracket in output from "info local" command in gdb?

Tags: gdb

What does `<>` angle bracket indicate? Here

```
(gdb) info local
agent = 0x8049ea3 <__libc_csu_init+35>
stun_addr = 0xbffff249 "stun.stprotocol.org"
stun_port = 3478
controlling = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows the location of the instruction and its offset.

So, in this example, `agent` points to the specific instruction located 35 bytes after the start of the `__libc_csu_init` function.